# Ascending order of Excel rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have the following rows in Excel:

[image]

How can I put them in an ascending order (i.e. notice how the row starting with 12 comes before that starting with 118).

Thanks.

Comment: Create additional column containing starting substring till the first point converted to numeric value. Sort by it.

Answer (score 3):

When sorting text, Excel looks at character codes which can be obtained using the `CODE` function.  `CODE(".")` returns 46 while `CODE("0")` is 48 so the text with `"."` in the 3rd position is seen as less than the string with `"0"` in the same position.

To sort on the numeric part of your strings you will need a helper column adjacent to your strings.  In B1 enter this formula:

`=VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1))`

The `VALUE` function converts whatever `LEFT` finds before the `"."` into a number which can then be sorted in correct numerical order so that 12 will be less than 118.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind reply. I tried the formula on a new column "B", but always getting the value "1". Why do you think is that? May I be using the formula incorrectly?

Comment: Go to the Formulas tab and click Evaluate Formula.  What does the `FIND(".",A1)` part evaluate to?

Answer (score 0):

For a "then" solution, one can use the `REPLACE()` function to do the hard work:

```
=VALUE(REPLACE(A1,FIND(".",A1),LEN(A1),""))
```

`REPLACE()`, used like this, is `slightly` more extensible than `LEFT()` by itself. Instead of, say, a `LEFT()` and a `RIGHT()` to get bits from each end, perhaps, then putting them back together, slight effort with `REPLACE()` where it decides how many characters to insert could do it nicely.

It looks in A1, searches it for a period character (which follows the important numerical portion in your image) and replaces it with the non-character `""`. It uses `FIND()` to do the locating, taking its numerical value as the starting position for its own replacements. It desires a value for the number of the replacement characters to use and we use `LEN()` to tell it to replace as many characters as in the original.

So we end up with the desired numerical portion of your examples plus some amount of... nothing... since the `""` adds no characters to the string.

And it IS a string at this point since `REPLACE()` is a string function and Excel assumes you want a string as output. Wrapping it all with `VALUE()` changes the type to being a number.

Numbers sort properly so "12" will sort before "118", for instance.

Note that since you are not using these values for anything but sorting, if you do not use the `VALUE()` function, things will still look like numbers and IF you can remember to make the right selection when sorting and Excel gives you the "Sort Warning" dialog box, you can just go with that. You'd have to always remember, of course, and never forget, but it would work nicely. However, since there's no cost to adding `VALUE()`, why not use it?

By the way, no good way to do it without the helper column. One could do quite a few things, but it always comes down to having to do the sort and needing those values for ordering the sort. Excel only really provides that choosing in the Sort functionality itself so one has to have actual cells, not, say, a Named Range, to refer to.

Even a "modern" (2021) ability to use the `SORT()` function, or `SORTBY()` doesn't help this because that just produces a nice list, in order, but... it produces it SOMEWHERE which is equivalent to using a helper column. So six of one, half a dozen of the other.

To sort in place with no helper column (of some kind), you'd need VBA. Which would work nicely. But a macro, to do it "in place", not a UDF.